# How to unit test rectangle packing algorithm

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I've recently implemented some rectangle bin packing algorithms for a project I'm working on. I've been testing it somewhat naively by generating lots of rectangles and looking at the results but I want to go at it more methodically.

The interface that's exposed publicly looks like this:

```
class RectPacker
{
public:
    RectPacker(int width, int height);
    virtual ~RectPacker();

    //////
    /// \brief fit a rectangle into the available space
    ///
    /// \param[in] width, height    size of the rectangle to be fitted
    /// \param[out] x, y            position where the rectangle was fitted (disregard if function returns false)
    /// \param[out] rotated         whether or not the rectangle was rotated during the fitting
    /// \return true if position for the rectangle could be found, false if rectangle could not be fitted.
    ///
    virtual bool findBestPosition(int width, int height, int& x, int& y, bool& rotated) = 0;

    //////
    /// \brief clear the rectangle packer
    ///
    /// Resets the packer to an empty state. This is usefull when you want to free up space.
    /// Since just freeing space will the space fragmented and degrade packing performance
    /// it is usually better to just clear the entire packer and repack all the remaining
    /// rectangles.
    ///
    virtual void clear() = 0;
};
```

Basically you initialize the packer with a bin size. Each call to findBestPosition allocates a chunk of that bin to a rectangle until it's full and can't fit any more (in which case the method will return false).

So, given that the system interface is so small, the algorithm is pretty complex and I can't inspect internal state, how would I go about writing unit tests for this?

My intuition tells me that I could just hammer it with a big amount of randomly generated rectangles. I would keep a list of the returned fittings and check whether they are all within the bounds of the bin and mutually disjoint. However, that doesn't test for certain degenerate cases (like stacking all rectangles on one side and leaving >80% space empty). Of course I could try to define a maximum allowed waste percentage and check for that when the algorithm starts to refuse fittings.

There are several dissatisfying aspects to this:

- how do I set the allowed waste percentage? It seems awfully arbitrary and wishy-washy to me. Set it too low and you get too many false positives, set it too high and you'll miss problems in the algorithm.
- I like my unit tests to be deterministic and reproducible. Random data doesn't feel right. But if I use the same set of rectangles every time I risk missing stuff.
- by tracking the returned fittings and analyzing them the tests themselves become so complex that they are prone to errors. Unit tests should be dead simple.
- Certain misbehavior only becomes apparent by looking at the data with a pair of human eyes. Not sure how to check that the algorithm is "well behaved". For example it might leave large gaps or it might fail to rotate the rectangles for maximum efficiency or it might rotate them all the wrong way (sign error) and waste space that way...

I know how to test it manually, but how to write a test suite for that? Am I making this more difficult than it is?

Comment: While not using the [Golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) to generate a series of rectangles by using the property of the spiral R1 = (a x Gr) x a, R2 = a x (a / Gr), ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that I'm never quite sure what I'm talking about when it comes to testing, here's how I'd go about thinking about this:

Why are you writing unit tests? By my understanding, unit testing is about making sure the code does something right.  Pack a bin with a certain area of rectangles. Try to pack a rectangle with area larger than the difference. Does it fit? It shouldn't. Pack a single rectangle. Is it on the edge. This is where you look for the simple constraints that should always hold, so you can catch it if you mess up a refactor or overlooked something. How could the algorithm violate the physics of your universe, and what's the simplest way you check that?

How *well* your algorithm performs is a different concern. This is benchmarking, not unit testing. Do you do better than random? How does it compare to other bin packing algorithms?

Testing and benchmarking serve two different purposes, and I would treat them separately.

Addressing specific points:

> But if I use the same set of rectangles every time I risk missing stuff.

You can't test everything. Handle all the cases you can think of. If something new comes up, lesson learned.

> how do I set the allowed waste percentage?

Look at the available literature and the context of the problem. How good do you need to be? How good is everyone else?

> Not sure how to check that the algorithm is "well behaved".

You could construct minimal examples for specific behaviors. For the correct rotation issue, fit a "wide" box into a "tall" bin, so the only solution is to rotate. Or build something like

```
|    |
|    |
|    |
|x   |
------
```

And try to insert

```
xxxx
```

Comment: Along with corner cases as mentioned, and a few static cases with known output, also try to create test cases any time your manual inspection (during development or test) finds an issue.  First make a test case that stimulates the behavior, the fix the issue.  This will help avoid regressions.